# Callback not being called in Facebook login flow

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

Ok this is bugging me for couple of hours now...

I have a MainActivity, calling TutorialActivity which is composed of a `ViewPager` and some other elements.

One of the pages in the `ViewPager` is a facebook login fragment named LoginFragment, showing the `LoginButton`.

My problem is that my callback is not being called after I click the `LoginButton`.

I've followed the entire tutorial for "Login with Facebook" on developers.facebook.com yet, I can't figure out what's wrong.

LoginFragment:

```
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment {

    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
    private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };

    public LoginFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_fragment,
                container, false);
        LoginButton authBtn = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        authBtn.setFragment(this);
        authBtn.setReadPermissions("user_friends");
        return view;
    }

    private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception e) {
        Log.v("FBLogin", "State changed!");
        Intent i = new Intent();
        Session.saveSession(session, i.getExtras());
        getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i);
        getActivity().finish();
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null &&
                (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed())) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
        }
        uiHelper.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        uiHelper.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my issue finally by moving everything related to `UiLifecycleHelper` to the activity holding the fragment and it worked.

In other words: `authBtn.setFragment(this)` does **NOT** mean you can put `UiLifecycleHelper` in your fragment!